# True persistent footers/headers in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, position, fixed

I've got persistent footers/headers in a jqm app I'm working on.
They work pretty much as expected, except when you tapping in the "white space" anywhere inside the [data-role="content"], the header and footer scroll out of view. Tapping in the content where there are no links or buttons again slides the header and footer back into place.

[Here is a prototype of the app I'm working on:](http://bear.hol.low.li/Pocket_Docent/index.html)

It's appropriate for pages where there is a long column of text. You get more screen real estate for reading the content. That's nice if it's what you expect.

But when you have a map page, it gets clunky - new users may see this as bug -- especially if they can't figure out how to get off the map page or another page with content.

Also when you're viewing a page with content that's shorter than the page length on a desktop, the footer actually climbs up into the page.

That's not what I expect.

How can I make data-position="fixed" really work the way I expect it to?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the `data-tap-toggle="false"` attribute to your header and footer, or in javascript:

```
$( ".selector" ).fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
```

Here is the API documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/fixedtoolbar/#option-tapToggle

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. There is so much to wade information in the api. Not knowing the right search term can sometimes hamper figuring it out on my own. I really appreciate it.